# Are parent class constructors called before initializing variables?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Are parent class constructors called before initializing variables, or will the compiler initialize the variables of the class first?

For example:

```
class parent {
  int a;
public:
  parent() : a(123) {};
};

class child : public parent {
  int b;
public:
            // question: is parent constructor done before init b?
  child() : b(456), parent() {};
}
```

Comment: So is your question whether you can control the base-class-constructor and derived-class member variable initialization order via the initializer list layout?

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/113-order-of-construction-of-derived-classes/

Comment: A thought, you could have checked this with printing to a console in the parent constructor and the constructor of a member variable, but now you got shiny answers.

Comment: @WhozCraig no. the control of the member variables is done by the position (first come first served), but im not sure if the base class or the members are first.

Comment: Then [this sample](http://ideone.com/C2CC6U) will likely demonstrate what I think you're asking if I understand the question correctly, and several answers below (hopefully all of them) will confirm this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, the base class is initialized before the members of the derived class and before the constructor body executes.

#### 12.6.2 Initializing bases and members [class.base.init]

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the
> following order:
>
> — First, and only for the constructor of the most
> derived class (1.8), virtual base classes are initialized in the order
> they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed
> acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of
> appearance of the base classes in the derived class
> base-specifier-list.
>
> — Then, direct base classes are initialized in
> declaration order as they appear in the base-specifier-list
> (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
>
> — Then, non-static
> data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the
> class definition (again regardless of the order of the
> mem-initializers).
>
> — Finally, the compound-statement of the
> constructor body is executed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the parent constructor is always called before the derived class. Otherwise, the derived class couldn't "alter" something set by the parent class.

Answer (score 2):

Just as some advice, you can usually just test things like this out yourself if you're not sure:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class parent {
protected:
  int a;
public:
  parent() : a(123) { cout << "in parent(): a == " << a << endl; };
};

class child : public parent {
  int b;
public:
            // question: is parent constructor done before init b?
  child() : b(456), parent() { cout << "in child(): a == " << a << ", b == " << b << endl; };
};

int main() {
  child c;
  return 0;
}
```

prints

```
in parent(): a == 123
in child(): a == 123, b == 456
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. b should be a class whose constructor print something.

Comment: I actually did a test before posting my question and i knew it was done first with the specific compiler i tested. What i was looking for is the definition as in Luchian Grigore's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15366747/1810087).

Answer (score 2):

I was redirected from [Initialize member before base constructor. Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942132/initialize-member-before-base-constructor-possible)
... and with some nit picking that is not exactly a duplicate due there is a workaround:

The value can initialize before base class by using multiple inheritance.

```
class parent {
    int a;
public:
    parent(int b) : a{123 + b} {};
};

class cousin {
protected:
    cousin() : b {456} {}
    int b;
};

class child : public cousin, public parent {
public:
    child() : cousin(), parent(b) {};
};
```

Now the b can be initialized and used in parent.

Comment: It  would be easier to inherit `cousin` by `parent`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,construction of objects starts from the parent class and comes to child classes, so the constructor calls are in that order. In case of destruction, this is exactly opposite.

Answer (score 0):

think of derived class as extra addition or extension of its base class, addition so it adds to something (this something must already exists).
then, another issue is initialization of members. here, you provided default constructor

```
public:
  parent() : a(123) {};
```

so the member will be default initialized with 123 even if you create parent this way:

```
parent p;
```

if there was no default constructor that initializes object with value

```
class parent {
public:
  int a;
};
```

than what will be by default in member depends, if the class is P.O.D then int will be default initialized to 0, but if it is not, i.e. you provide more members such as string or vector

```
class parent {
public:
  int a;
  std::string s;
  std::vector<int> v;
};
```

int will have random value if there is no default constructor that initializes it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to work around the language to construct class members before calling the base class. Here is how I would do it:

```
class C
{
};

class A
{
  public:
  A(C *ptr);
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
    B() : A(allocateC()) {}
    private:

    C *m_ptr;
    C *allocateC() { m_ptr = new C; return m_ptr; }
};
```

I am currently looking at how I could use placement new to store the class members initialized into the class object memory instead of placing them on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Another method of subverting the usual initialisation order.

Like Tama's answer this applies more to the duplicate question: [Initialize member before base constructor. Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942132/initialize-member-before-base-constructor-possible).

This only works because our `Value` is never reinitialised in the derived class. It is perhaps more useful to demonstrate that the often confused processes of memory allocation and initialisation may be, infact, two distinct steps. **For various reasons I would err away from using this method in a production program**!

MWE:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    int BaseValue;

    Base(int baseValue) : BaseValue(baseValue)
    {
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    int Value;

    explicit Derived() : Base((Value = 42, Value)) 
    {
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    std::cout << d.BaseValue << ", " << d.Value;
    return 0;
}
```