# What constructor activate first, the class objects or the class parent?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, default-constructor

For example:

```
Class A
{
  A();
}

Class B
{
  A a;
  B(A& m_a) : a(m_a)
}
```

Which constructor will apply first? the A() constructor of the B parent, or the A object inside class B?

Comment: -1 not real code (also, no indentation)

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question means; which is the "A() constructor of the B parent", and which is the "A object inside class B"?

Comment: Not real code to demonstrate the problem

Comment: I don't know why people are reacting with hostility to this question. It reads clearly to me.

Comment: @Boann: Your answer talks about subclasses, but there are none here... (basically, the question isn't as clear as you think ;) )

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Ohhh. I hadn't noticed that, but it's clear from the words I think.

Comment: Actually you can figure it out with an execution where both constructors have std::cout. The output will show you the order of its execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking the order of the parent and derived class constructors, see [Are parent class constructors called before initializing variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366621/are-parent-class-constructors-called-before-initializing-variables).

In short, the base (or parent) class (looks like `A` in your case) constructor will complete first.

Answer (score -1):

The parent constructor will execute first, then the subclass constructor will initialize the variable.

Comment: So what are "parent" and "subclass" here?