# Initialize member before base constructor. Possible?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
class A{
public:
    A(int* i){
        std::cout << "in A()" << i << std::endl;
    }
};

class B: public A{
public:
    B(): i{new int{10}}, A{i}{
        std::cout << "in B()" << std::endl; 
    }

private:
    int* i;
};

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

In `A` constructor I have 0 (which is expected). But I want to initialize `i` before. Is it possible at all?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish. However, just off the top of my head: A's constructor and any initializing performed within it will always be performed before B's constructor is called. The only way to force the initializing to happen first in B() is to declare a member in it that A doesn't have.  Even then, all of the inherited members will be initialized first in A(). Why don't you tell us WHY you want to do this, maybe we can help with that.

Comment: It is like asking God to create the sockets for your eyes in the skull before creating the skull

Comment: You can't initialize members before base classes, but you can approximate it by adding a base class to hold the members you want to initialize early. Base classes are initialized in order.

https://godbolt.org/g/puv6T5

`struct Bi_ { int* i; };   class B : private Bi_, public A {...};`

Comment: **This has been overzealously closed** by someone assuming the answer is *no*. However this is asking if it is **possible** to subvert the normal initialisation order (which, as has been pointed out, is possible, if you really want (e.g. `Base((Variable=x, Variable))`). The "duplicate" is merely asking for the usual order, which is a different question entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is a data member of class `B`, so in order to be created, an object of class `B` has to be created first.

As @Arthur commented, there is a way though like this:

```
B(): A{i = new int{10}} { 
  std::cout << "in B()" << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: There is a way, though. You can do:`B(): A{i = new int{10}}{ std::cout << "in B()" << std::endl; }`

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible since the base class initialization is always prior to derived class initialization.

> #### C++11, 12.6.2
>
> <sup>10</sup> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>
> - First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (1.8), virtual base classes are initialized in the order they appear on a depth-ﬁrst left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes, where "left-to-right" is the order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class base-speciﬁer-list.
> - Then, direct base classes are initialized in declaration order as they appear in the base-speciﬁer-list (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
> - Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class deﬁnition (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
> - Finally, the compound-statement of the constructor body is executed.

Answer (score -1):

> Initialize member before base constructor. Possible?

No, that is not possible. The standard mandates that the base classes be initialized first before the members of the class are initialized.

```
B(): i{new int{10}}, A{i}{
    std::cout << "in B()" << std::endl; 
}
```

is transformed to:

```
B(): A{i}, i{new int{10}}{
    std::cout << "in B()" << std::endl; 
}
```