# CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer (new/delete) classes

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

I am receiving the "Debug error" CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap. But I don't understand why and can't find any similar examples.

The full code is...
Although I think it may just be a problem with main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <array>

using namespace std;
// Declare global consts
const double pi = 3.1415926583;


// Base class Shape
class Shape{
protected:
    double *sides;
public:
    Shape(const int n){ //parameterized for n dimensional shape
    sides = new double[n];
}
// need virtual destructor
virtual ~Shape(){
    delete[] sides;
}
virtual double area() const = 0; // pure virtual function for area
virtual double volume() const = 0; // pure virtual function for volume
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Derived classes for 2D and 3D Shapes
class Shape2D : public Shape{ // inherit shape
protected:
    int n = 2; //n denotes the number of dimensions
public:
    // default constructor
    Shape2D() :Shape(n){}
    // param constructor
    Shape2D(const double side1, const double side2) :Shape(n){
        sides[0] = side1; sides[1] = side2;
    }
    virtual ~Shape2D(){} //virtual destructor
    double volume() const { cout << "trying to calculate volume of 2d   shape..." << endl; return 0; };
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//2D shapes
class Rectangle : public Shape2D{
public:
    // constructors
    Rectangle() :Shape2D() {}
    Rectangle(const double side1, const double side2) :Shape2D(side1, side2){}
    ~Rectangle(){}
    double area() const { return (sides[0] * sides[1]); }
};

int main(){
    Shape **ShapePointer = new Shape*[2];
    ShapePointer[0] = new Rectangle(2, 5);
    ShapePointer[1] = new Rectangle(1, 3);
    // clean up 
    delete ShapePointer[0];
    delete ShapePointer[1];
    delete[] ShapePointer;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On an unrelated (perhaps) I don't see the need for `ShapePointer`. Just have a plain array of pointers to `Shape`, as in `Shape* ShapeArray[2] = { new Rectangle(...), new Rectangle(...) }`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that originally and had this issue.

Comment: More related to your question, can't you run in the debugger and catch the error as you run your program? Then you should be able to locate where in your code it happens. Or at least add lot of debug-logging to help you narrow it down?

Comment: `double *sides;` -- Simply use `std::vector<double> sides;` as your `Shape` object is neither safely copyable nor assignable the way it's written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Danger!!!

```
protected:
    int n = 2; //n denotes the number of dimensions
public:
    // default constructor
    Shape2D() :Shape(n){}
```

`n` is undefined when you initialize `Shape(n)`

Same problem with

```
Shape2D(const double side1, const double side2) :Shape(n)
```

If you can, define `n` as `static const` (or `static constexpr`, because you tagged C++11)

```
 protected:
    static constexpr int n = 2; //n denotes the number of dimensions
```

Otherwise you should define a static `const`/`constexpr` variable (say `nDef`), with value `2`, and initialize both `n` and `Shape()` with this constant.

Anyway, take in count that, now, `Shape` (a base class for `Shape2D`) is initialized **before** `n`, that is a member of the class.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the following two lines of the code:
`int n = 2; //n denotes the number of dimensions`
`Shape2D(const double side1, const double side2) :Shape(n){ ... }`

The problem is the `Shape()` gets executed before the `n` is initialized. See [constructors-called-before-initializing-variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366621/are-parent-class-constructors-called-before-initializing-variables) for details.

To solution to this would be to create a the following methods in the `Shape` class

```
protected: 
void InitializeBuffer(const int n)
{
sides = new double[n]
}
```

and instead of initialize the `sides` in the parent constructor, call this `InitializeBuffer` with in the constructor of the `Shape2D` class

```
Shape2D(const double side1, const double side2) :Shape()
{
    InitializeBuffer (n);
    sides[0] = side1; sides[1] = side2;
}
```