# Initialization of a base class reference from a derived class member

Tags: c++, inheritance, initialization, member

I have two classes, `Base` and `Derived`. `Derived` constructs `Base` using its own member object, which inherits from `Base::BaseChild`.

```
struct Base
{
    struct BaseChild
    {
        int x = 5;
    };
    Base(BaseChild& c): baseData(c), constantVar(c.x) 
    {
       assert(constantVar == 5);
    }
    int getX() const {return baseData.x;}

private:
    const int constantVar;
    BaseChild& baseData;
};


struct Derived: public Base
{
    struct DerivedChild: public BaseChild
    {
        double y = 4.0;
    };
    Derived(): Base(data) {}

private:
    DerivedChild data;
};


Derived myObject;
assert(myObject.getX() == 5);
```

**Reasoning**: I do this in this way because everything seems pretty encapsulated for my case, where I need to send Childs to swap their content (`vector`, `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`) with other Childs, keeping child memory address, and I still can access to Child object from base class without the need of a virtual function, which was killing my app performance.

**Question**: I've read another post [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366621/are-parent-class-constructors-called-before-initializing-variables), where it states initialization of a `Derived` member before the `Base` isn't possible. So the `constantVar` assert would always fail. However `getX()` works fine, after the constructor, and I'm interested in these functions which are called once the constructor ends. Is this safe? Or is there any hidden danger here?

Comment: Are you okay with removing all attempts to read/write the derived class' data in the constructor (and push that functionality out into member functions)? If so, I think we can achieve what you want with CRTP

Comment: Yes, I'm ok with that. However I'm not sure if there is another risk of undefined behavior, even if I don't read/write in the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base class `Base` of `Derived` is constructed before the member `data`.

As a result `data` will not be initialized when you pass a reference to it to `Base`'s constructor. The initialization will happen after that constructor call.

You are however trying to read the member `x` of `data` in `Base`'s constructor. At this point `data`'s lifetime has not started yet and accessing the value of a non-static data member of an object outside its lifetime causes undefined behavior.

Whether or not the assertions succeed isn't significant. Undefined behavior allows for either outcome.

The situation would be potentially different (although technically not rules in the standard) if you were not trying to access the value of `data` inside `Base`'s constructor, but only storing the reference to it.